# Using open source SNES emulator code to turn a rom file into a self-contained executable game

Tags: executable, emulation, rom

Would it be possible to take the source code from a SNES emulator (or any other game system emulator for that matter) and a game ROM for the system, and somehow create a single self-contained executable that lets you play that particular ROM without needing either the individual rom or the emulator itself to play? Would it be difficult, assuming you've already got the rom and the emulator source code to work with?

Answer (score 3):

It shouldn't be too difficult if you have the emulator source code.  You can use a method that is often used to store images in c source files.

Basically, what you need to do is create a `char *` variable in a header file, and store the contents of the rom file in that variable.  You may want to write a script to automate this for you.

Then, you will need to alter the source code so that instead of reading the rom in from a file, it uses the in memory version of the rom, stored in your variable and included from your header file.

It may require a little bit of work if you need to emulate file pointers and such, or you may be lucky and find that the rom loading function just loads the whole file in at once.  In this case it would probably be as simple as replacing the file load function with a function to return your pointer.

However, be careful for licensing issues.  If the emulator is licensed under the GPL, you may not be legally allowed to store a proprietary file in the executable, so it would be worth checking that, especially before you release / distribute it (if you plan to do so).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, more than possible, been done many times.  Google: static binary translation.  Graham Toal has a good howto paper on the subject, should show up early in the hits.  There may be some code out there I may have left some code out there.

Completely removing the rom may be a bit more work than you think, but not using an emulator, definitely possible.  Actually, both requirements are possible and you may be surprised how many of the handheld console games or set top box games are translated and not emulated.  Esp platforms like those from Nintendo where there isnt enough processing power to emulate in real time.

You need a good emulator as a reference and/or write your own emulator as a reference.  Then you need to write a disassembler, then you have that disassembler generate C code (please dont try to translate directly to another target, I made that mistake once, C is portable and the compilers will take care of a lot of dead code elimination for you).  So an instruction of a make believe instruction set might be:

```
add r0,r0,#2
```

And that may translate into:

```
//add r0,r0,#2
r0=r0+2;
do_zflag(r0);
do_nflag(r0);
```

It looks like the SNES is related to the 6502 which is what Asteroids used, which is the translation I have been working on off and on for a while now as a hobby.  The emulator you are using is probably written and tuned for runtime performance and may be difficult at best to use as a reference and to check in lock step with the translated code.  The 6502 is nice because compared to say the z80 there really are not that many instructions.  As with any variable word length instruction set the disassembler is your first big hurdle.  Do not think linearly, think execution order, think like an emulator, you cannot linearly translate instructions from zero to N or N down to zero.  You have to follow all the possible execution paths, marking bytes in the rom as being the first byte of an instruction, and not the first byte of an instruction.  Some bytes you can decode as data and if you choose mark those, otherwise assume all other bytes are data or fill.  Figuring out what to do with this data to get rid of the rom is the problem with getting rid of the rom.  Some code addresses data directly others use register indirect meaning at translation time you have no idea where that data is or how much of it there is.  Once you have marked all the starting bytes for instructions then it is a trivial task to walk the rom from zero to N disassembling and or translating.

Good luck, enjoy, it is well worth the experience.

Comment: The SNES actually uses a 65816 processor, as i recall.  It's mostly binary compatible with the 6502, but flags can be set to give you 16-bit registers and offsets and such.  Other than that, yeah.  Pretty simple, if tedious, to disassemble.